# Nomi dei mesi: solo una conicidenza?

Tags: etymology

Salve a tutti,

Mi è capitata questa domanda da uno studente:

Perché questi mesi si chiamano così?
 - OTTObre 
 - NOVEmbre
 - DICEmbre

Perché OTTO, NOVE e D(I)EC?

Forse una volta ottobre era l'ottavo mese?

Ho insegnato ai miei studenti a ricordare i numeri usando DICIAssette,
DICIotto,
etc... ma ora sono un po' confusa!

Grazie!

Comment: Vedi: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendario_romano.

Comment: Se sei un'insegnante, forse dovresti essere in grado di svolgere [qualche ricerca da sola](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): non è esattamente una nozione misteriosa. Basta vedere sulla Wikipedia come menzionato da Charo, o partire dall'etimologia di uno di questi nomi di mesi, o in vari altri modi...

Answer (score 9):

Non è affatto una coincidenza: nella [riforma del calendario romano al tempo di Numa Pompilio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gennaio) vennero aggiunti i due mesi di gennaio e febbraio. A quanto pare il periodo invernale veniva prima considerato a parte.

Più tardi, il settimo e l'ottavo mese presero il nome da Giulio Cesare e da Ottaviano Augusto diventando *Julius* e *Augustus* da [*quintilis*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luglio) e [*sextilis*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agosto).

I mesi successivi conservarono il nome precedente. Quindi settembre, ottobre, novembre e dicembre erano effettivamente i mesi dal settimo al decimo. Va notato che marzo era rimasto comunque il primo mese (inizio della primavera), ma poi l'inizio dell'anno fu spostato, intorno al secondo secolo, a gennaio.

In molte regioni l'inizio dell'anno rimase fissato in marzo per vari secoli. Solo in tempi relativamente recenti tutti si sono uniformati a gennaio.